# Creating and modifying objects inside Stream

Tags: java, java-8, stream, java-stream

I have a problem which is something like this.

```
myList
    .stream()
    .x->y=f(x)
    .x -> h(x) = x'
    .x' = y(x')
```

So, I have a list which I want to stream and take `x` and perform `f(x)` and store it in `y` and then do a `h(x)` and store it back in `x` and then use `y` and `x'` and store it in `x'` again.

Comment: you're creating f(x) but not using it.. you can just go forward applying your different functions one after another... .stream().map(x -> f(x)).map(y-> h(x)).map(z -> y(z)).collect(Collectors.asList())...

Comment: why don't you go with traditional for loop strategy, it will make it simpler and the code will look readable too. Why i am saying this is because variables such as y, h(x) to which you are assigning values should be effective final if you by lambda and stream way

Comment: What is your actual question? Is it that you want to have a working code example for that pseudo-code? Or does your current code have a problem and does not run correctly? To me it is hard to follow your example. Maybe it would be better if you make it more concrete, not that abstract.

Comment: probably you need to ues smth like `Pair<x, f(x)>` instead of `y` and then work with stream of pairs

Comment: dont split it into three, just do `f(x)(h(x))`

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to do that with the stream, in my opinion it doesn't make much sense to do it this way, it's much easier with a classic loop. here you can see a stream way:

```
myList.stream()
    .map(x -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(h(x), f(x)))
    .map(entry -> g(entry.getKey()/* x' */, entry.getValue()/* y */))
    .forEach(x2 -> System.out.println("x': "+x2));
```

Edited

The same code with the classic loop:

```
for (Integer x: myList){
    y = f(x);
    x = h(x);
    x2 = g(x, y);
    System.out.println("x': "+x2);
}
```

Comment: Nice. Can you add a traditional loop variant too?

Comment: why don't `map(x -> g(h(x), f(x)))`

Comment: @dehasi That's a good idea, I did it that way because I wasn't sure I understood the OP in depth.

Comment: @DavidPérezCabrera in 9, you could use `Map#entry` or `List#of` with two values, in 8, `Arrays#asList` instead of `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`